# Correct LINES TERMINATED BY when importing uploaded CSV into MySQL table from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql, csv, load-data-infile

I’m having trouble identifying how my CSV’s lines are terminated. I’m using the following PHP code to load data from a CSV into my DB.

```
mysql_query('LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "temp/test.csv"
             INTO TABLE test
             FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
             LINES TERMINATED BY "///"
             IGNORE 1 LINES (one, two, three, four, five)');
```

Now when I use `LINES TERMINATED BY "///"`, the data is put into my DB properly, except for the fact that the 1st column on each row is “a return” followed by the cell data. That’s not what I want, I want the return to disappear.

I think that the sequence of last column cell, `///`, return and first column cell in the CSV is split by `///` and should be split by `///` + return. I should change the `LINES TERMINATED BY`. I’ve tried `\n`, `\r`, `\r\n`, `\n\r`. After a while I tried `<br>` and knew I needed help.

I’m using MS Office on a Mac and saving my CSV as `Comma Separated Values (.csv)` ([sample](http://soliddev.us/temp/test.csv)). I’ve also tried the mentioned `LINES TERMINATED BY` with `MS-DOS Comma Separated` and `Windows Comma Separated` files.

Result of `SELECT HEX(one) FROM test` after running my query:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0D6131
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0D6132
)
Array
(
    [0] => 0D6133
)
```

Comment: `0D` is carriage return (`\r`). (And `61` is `A`, `30`–`39` are numbers `0`-`9`.) When I use your query with `LINES TERMINATED BY "///\r"`, it imports the CSV all right on my MySQL 5.1.49.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Correct query

Your CSV has rows delimited by three slashes and carriage return. Just use `LINES TERMINATED BY "///\r"` in your query and it should work. At least it works for me on my MySQL 5.1.49.

```sql
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE "temp/test.csv"
INTO TABLE test
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","
LINES TERMINATED BY "///\r"
IGNORE 1 LINES (one, two, three, four, five)
```

## Debugging unprintable characters

When in doubt about what the unprintable characters are, you can always look at hexdump and decode the characters manually. Usually these characters are ASCII. On *NIXes, see `man ascii`, otherwise look the table up on Internet (e.g. http://man-ascii.com/).

In MySQL, hexdump of a string is obtained by `HEX()` function application, e.g.

```sql
SELECT HEX(one) FROM test
```

In POSIX shell, hexdump is generated using

```sh
od -t x1 temp/test.csv
```

If you do not want to be that hardcore, for common whitespace it is enough to convert it to C escape sequences (e.g. `\r` for carriage return) using

```sql
od -c temp/test.csv
```

Maybe even simpler (but generally harder to explain) approach to identifying EOL type is just using the text editor of your choice and letting it tell you. CSV is a plain text format (in contrast to binary format). E.g. in Vim open the file and run `se ff?`. This will show you `fileformat=<EOL-type>` where `<EOL-type>` is

- `unix` for `\n`
- `dos` for `\r\n`
- `mac` for `\r`

## Beware multiple escaping levels

Notice that at the beginning of my answer I wrote just the query, not PHP command to execute it. In SQL, some characters are special and need to be escaped to be taken literally (quote inside string), other gain their special meaning through escaping (`n` in `\n`). In PHP, the SQL query must be placed in string, where another level of escaping takes place (and for different characters!). Another level of escaping comes e.g. when you call PHP from shell as `php -r '…'`.

If you want to be sure that you got the escaping right, print the query before sending it to database.

```sql
$query = '…';
print $query;
#$result = mysql_query($query);
```

## `mysql` API was deprecated in PHP 5.5, removed in PHP 7.0

The old `mysql` API (`mysql_*` functions) was [deprecated in PHP 5.5](http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php) and [removed in PHP 7.0](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php), it will not be available in future versions. Consult the PHP manual for [choice of MySQL API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). See also other [relevant](//stackoverflow.com/a/12860046/2157640) [answers](//stackoverflow.com/a/13944958/2157640).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `///` occurrences from your CSV file.

Make sure your CSV file is uploaded in ASCII (not BINARY) FTP format.

Then query:

```
mysql_query("LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'temp/test.csv' 
             INTO TABLE test 
             FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
             LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n' 
             IGNORE 1 LINES (one, two, three, four, five)");
```

Comment: I did just as you said, deleted all cells with /// from the CSV, switched transfer mode to ASCII, uploaded CSV, replaced my query with yours (copied/pasted). No rows are imported this way.

Comment: I updated my answer a few minutes ago, are you sure you used the updated with TWO slashes before the `n` (`LINES TERMINATED BY '\\n'`)

Comment: Drat, well, sorry! :)